# Adobe Acrobat Reader - is that possible log out from OneDrive storage without removing it?

Tags: pdf, onedrive, adobe-acrobat

I am using Acrobat Reader to edit pdf stored at Microsoft OneDrive cloud.
This is easy doable by adding "Other file storage" entry.
I would like to force two factor authentication each time I want to open my file.
The only way I have found is just removing the file storage and re-add it again.

Is that a more convenient way to force authentication open document opening?